TIFFStreamOpen fails to read from a memory stream
I've read a GeoTIFF file into a std::vector<std::uint8_t> which gets passed around as a const ref to various functions.  One of those functions I need to open the image as a TIFF* so I can read some of the tags.  As these files can be very large (10s or 100s of megabytes), I don't want to copy the image in memory.  I've found these answers which have similar approaches and definitely looked promising, but then TIFFStreamOpen fails using the following code:
class vectorbuf : public std::streambuf 
{
public:
    vectorbuf( std::vector<uint8_t>& v )
    {
        setg( (char*)v.data(), (char*)v.data(), (char*)(v.data() + v.size()) );
    }

    ~vectorbuf() {}
};

void GeotiffUtils::ProcessImage( const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& imgData )
{
    detail::vectorbuf strmBuf( const_cast<std::vector<std::uint8_t>&>(imgData) );
    std::istream memStrm( &strmBuf );

    TIFF* memTiff = TIFFStreamOpen( "MemTiff", &memStrm );

    std::uint16_t orientation = 1;
    auto success = TIFFGetField( memTiff, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, &orientation );

    //... (other processing)

    TIFFClose( memTiff );

    //... (even more processing)
}

I have been able to use TIFFStreamOpen by copying the data into a std::string and std::istringstream like so:
void GeotiffUtils::ProcessImage( const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& imgData )
{
    std::string imgString( imgData.begin(), imgData.end() );
    std::istringstream memStrm( imgString, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in );

    TIFF* memTiff = TIFFStreamOpen( "MemTiff", &memStrm);

    std::uint16_t orientation = 1;
    auto success = TIFFGetField( memTiff, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, &orientation );

    //... (other processing)

    TIFFClose( memTiff );

    //... (even more processing)
}

This is obviously less than ideal with large files.
Is there a reason why the copied data can be read successfully but not the original vector?

I think it would be very helpful to state what error you get in your first example. Also, is it a runtime error or a compile error?

Runtime, memTiff is null, indicating TIFFStreamOpen failed to read the TIFF.

I do not have any experience with libtiff, but I can give some recommendation on how to debug. TIFFStreamOpen calls TIFFClientOpen. I am pretty sure, that the issue is somewhere in this function. The documentation of libtiff mentions:
"All error messages are directed to the TIFFErrorExtR() routine. Likewise, warning messages are directed to the TIFFWarningExtR() routine."
(http://www.libtiff.org/functions/TIFFOpen.html#diagnostics)
I think it would be good, to set up a way to print the stuff directed there.

I've added some error handling, I'm getting "Seek error accessing TIFF directory", so I'm trying to override the seekpos and seekoff methods.

The seekpos and seekoff methods in std::streambuf seem to be the issue and are what's preventing TIFFStreamOpen from completing, you have to hold onto a reference to your buffer and override those methods
class vectorbuf : public std::streambuf 
{
public:
    vectorbuf( const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& buf ) :
        m_Buffer( buf )
    {
        char* dataPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(const_cast<std::uint8_t*>(m_Buffer.data()));
        setg( dataPtr, dataPtr, dataPtr + m_Buffer.size() );
    }

    ~vectorbuf() {}

    std::streampos seekoff( std::streamoff offset, std::ios_base::seekdir direction, std::ios_base::openmode mode ) override
    {
        auto pos = gptr();
        char* dataPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(const_cast<std::uint8_t*>(m_Buffer.data()));

        assert( mode = std::ios::in );

        switch ( direction )
        {
        case std::ios::beg:
            pos = dataPtr + offset;
            break;
        case std::ios::cur:
            pos += offset;
            break;
        case std::ios::end:
            pos = dataPtr + m_Buffer.size() + offset;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        setg( dataPtr, pos, dataPtr + m_Buffer.size() );
        return std::distance( dataPtr, pos );
    }

    std::streampos seekpos( std::streampos pos, std::ios_base::openmode mode ) override
    {
        char* dataPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(const_cast<std::uint8_t*>(m_Buffer.data()));
        assert( mode = std::ios::in );

        setg( dataPtr, dataPtr + pos, dataPtr + m_Buffer.size() );
        return pos;
    }

private:
    const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& m_Buffer;
};

Since this is a read-only stream buffer (and TIFFStreamOpen ignores the std::ios::binary flag), I decided to be (more) const correct and continue to only handle the get pointer.

Nice to hear that it works now.
